# Get second seconds highest value for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have some machines that are configured with with some settings. these settings change from time to time and the expiring date is stored in the database. the expiring date of one setting is the start time of the new setting at the same time. Given the following table

```
id          machineId              expiringDate
1           1                      2020-08-21 12:56:14
2           1                      2020-08-21 13:43:23
3           1                      2020-08-24 07:38:07
4           1                      NULL
5           2                      NULL
6           3                      2020-08-21 11:50:39
7           3                      NULL
```

how could I come to the following result where `startDate` is the `expiringDate` of the previous entry from a machine and `startDate` is `null` if there is no previous entry

```
id          machineId      expiringDate             startDate
1           1              2020-08-21 12:56:14      NULL
2           1              2020-08-21 13:43:23      2020-08-21 12:56:14
3           1              2020-08-24 07:38:07      2020-08-21 13:43:23
4           1              NULL                     2020-08-24 07:38:07
5           2              NULL                     NULL  
6           3              2020-08-21 11:50:39      NULL
7           3              NULL                     2020-08-21 11:50:39
```

so far i only managed to get the second highest value of the whole table but i got no clue how to do it for any class and even for any row.

**MySQL version 5.17.19**

Comment: do you use MySQL version 8 and above?

Comment: no its version 5.7. updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a version of MySQL 5.7 or earlier, then we can try using a correlated subquery here to find the lag of the expiring date:

```
SELECT
    id,
    machineId,
    expiringDate,
    (SELECT t2.expiringDate FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.machineId = t1.machineId AND t2.id < t1.id
     ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1) startDate
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    machineId,
    id;

id | machineId | expiringDate        | startDate          
---+-----------+---------------------+-------------------
 1 |         1 | 2020-08-21 12:56:14 | null              
 2 |         1 | 2020-08-21 13:43:23 | 2020-08-21 12:56:14
 3 |         1 | 2020-08-24 07:38:07 | 2020-08-21 13:43:23
 4 |         1 | null                | 2020-08-24 07:38:07
 5 |         2 | null                | null               
 6 |         3 | 2020-08-21 11:50:39 | null               
 7 |         3 | null                | 2020-08-21 11:50:39
```

### Demo

If you are using MySQL 8+, then the `LAG` analytic function can be used:

```
SELECT
    id,
    machineId,
    expiringDate,
    LAG(expiringDate) OVER (PARTITION BY machineId ORDER BY id) startDate
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    machineId,
    id;
```

Note carefully in that both versions of the query above, we can't use the expiry date as the order in which the lag should appear, because this very value itself may not be there (and `NULL` doesn't have any sense of order).  So instead, using the `id` value generates the ordering you seem to want here for finding the lag values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` if your mysql version is 8+

```
select id, machineid,expiringDate, 
       lag(expiringDate) over(partition by machineid order by id) as startdate
from tablename
```